# How to check if all the variables in the object is empty?

Tags: java

JSON response:

```
{
  "id": "",
  "status": "",
  "Date": "",
  "Name": ""
}
```

When I try to map it with the class using object mapper.
Name of class is Demo with the field same in json response.
It mapped like:

```
Demo(id=, status=, Date=, Name=)
```

There are around 10-15 variables in the response.
I want to know if all the variables of Demo object are empty.

Comment: To start with, what JSON parser are you using, and where is your code? Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Just to understand your requirements: why do you want to know that?

Comment: You see, if making such checks is an important aspect of your work, then maybe: do use an object mapper. Instead have the response turned into a map for example, or well, something like a JsonNode, as pointed out in one of the answers. The point of an object mapper is to give you type safety. Which you give up when using reflection. And worse: you spent a lot of CPU cycles for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

by using

```
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jString);

node.isNull();
```

you will get node is null or not
using

```
node.get("id").isNull();
node.get("id").isEmpty();
```

you can verify the content of JsonNode

Comment: I agree, using a "raw" JsonNode class is better than doing mapping first, to then use reflection to get back to the fields.

Answer (score 1):

A *pure* Java solution<sup>**1**</sup> could be using reflection. Here a very simple implementation, mostly to show the idea (not complete, assuming fields are `String`, poor (no) exception handling):

```
public static boolean isEmpty(Demo demo) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    for (var field : Demo.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (field.getType() == String.class) {
            var value = (String) field.get(demo);
            if (value != null && !value.isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

It could be improved for example by adding more types, using annotation on fields, ...

<sup>**1**: question is only tagged `java`</sup>
<sub>`var` was introduced in Java 10; use the concrete type (`for (Field...` or `String value...`) if using previous version of Java</sub>

Comment: Thanks, It worked.  change type var field to Field field in for loop.

Comment: Just saying: of course reflection works, but depending on context, it is a rather weird approach to first use reflection to turn JSON into a distinct Java class, to then use reflection to somehow "reverse" that operation to get to all the fields.